# Windows Server 2016 Installation doesn't found Network adpter (Hard Drive Found!)

Tags: networking, windows-server-2016, dell, ethernet, 10gbethernet

I have a just bought PowerEdge T640 server and i am trying to install Windows Server 2016 Standard.
I have downloaded the Windows Server 2016 ISO and mount a bootable pendrive using Rufus.
I boot the T640 Server and insert the pendrive and it recognizes it, so i start the installation.
The problem comes when i have to choose where to install Windows as no Disk appers.
I have an 240GB SSD Disk.
I need some help on how to make this SDD visible for the installation program.
Thx for help.

Edit:
I have installed Windows Server 2016 after investigating through Lifecycle Controller.
Then i have set the IP address in the Network configuration and i have checked with ping that while in the LifeCycle ping works, another laptop in the LAN sees the T640.
Then i save settings in T640 and reestart server
The Server works fine but ping doesn't works now, i check the server and no Ethernet adapter appears.
It's supposed to have two Bradcom Adv. Dual 10GBASE - T Ethernet adapters.
Thx in advance

Comment: It probably has an internal Storage Controller which you have to configure first. Check the BIOS and also boot without the pendrive and read the messages on the screen. There is probably a key combo you have to press to enter the storage controller BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Lifecycle Controller to install the operating system. It will inject the drivers that Windows needs to find the hard drive.

Comment: I have used it but after installation didn't found the Network adapter, while in LifeCycle i can make ping to server

Comment: Is Windows Server 2016 a supported OS on that model server?

Comment: It's supposed yes: https://www.dell.com/support/home/es/es/esbsdt1/drivers/supportedos/poweredge-t640

Answer (score 0):

The above answer usually works, I'm leaving this here in case you can't access the Lifecycle Controller for whatever reason.

You can download the driver from Dell's website, in your case:

[PowerEdge T640](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/poweredge-t640/drivers)

In the case of Windows Server 2016 the package would be:

> Windows Server 2016 64bit driver for PERC S140 Controller

Also, make sure the drive has been enabled, either through the iDRAC or the server's boot settings by creating a virtual drive with the 240GB SSD you mentioned.